# laravel and removing redirecting from a logout

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I try to add a function

```
public function postLogout() {
    //Auth::logout();
    return response()->json(['msg' => 'You have signed out']);
}
```

into file

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php
```

and use a route

```
Route::get('log_out', ['as' => 'auth.log_out', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogout']);
```

How to get down to a automatic redirecting from url http://localhost/myproj/public/log_out in that cases???
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by Automatic ? You want to sign out the user and redirect afterwards, right ? You can redirect and flash a message at the same time which makes sense in this scenario.

```
Route::get('log_out', function () {
   //Auth::logout();
   return redirect('log_in')->with('status', 'You have signed out!');
});
```

Read more [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-named-routes)